# Check if the user location is near of some points

Tags: ios, gps, userlocation

I have a question about GPS alarm.

I have some points (latitude and longitude). I need a way to check if the user location is near to some of these points (approximately are 1800 points).

If I remember correctly there is a best practice to do this: to be notified when GPS position is in a certain region. This allows for optimizations regarding the battery.

Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: If my answer is exactly what you are looking for, please upvote and mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1800 points as per 1800 different regions to be monitored?

It is not possible. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html):

For this reason, Core Location limits to 20 the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a single app.

If you have more than 20 regions to be monitored, this is what you can do:-

1. When the user launches your app, get the user's location and send the location to your server
2. After the server gets the user location, gathers all the points within N Kilometres (KM) radius.
3. If the points within N KM are less than 20, then send all the points to your user to be monitored.
4. If the points within N KM are more than 20, your server has to reduce the points based on the smaller radius (eg: N-1 KM)

I have developed a region monitoring app myself and this is what we do.

Comment: do you think that are there some different ways to obtain same result?

Comment: How big are your points in terms of radius? And What are the distance between 1 point to another (roughly)?

Comment: Updated my answer above.

Comment: there are not regions, but they are not really regions are just positions. We can consider these as a POI (eg restaurants). 
Some of these points can be very close to each other (few meters) other very lontandi (for example 1000 km)

Comment: I think you need more than 1 solution. For places that are some distance from each other, you can use Region monitoring. For places that are closed by, I think you should look at iBeacon (which I am not too familiar with yet)

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by **near to some of these points**.

You could use the haversine formula to calculate the distance between your current location and each of the set of test points.  The calculation involves a fair number of trig functions so could work out computationally intensive but depending upon your application it may not be necessary to recalculate more than once a minute or so.