# CoreLocation Region radius accuracy?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location, geofencing

I wanted to implement geofencing within some regions. Since I am not currently using an iPhone to test out my application, I wanted to test out the Core Location framework on the simulator. I created a few simple regions with a 100m radiuses. I have two different regions that have a center at the following coordinates: `39.541957 latitude, -121.749642 longitude` and another with the coordinates `39.537224 latitude, -121.754556 longitude`. However, when I use the iPhone simulator and try to enter one of the regions, I happen to enter both regions instead of just one region, even though I set the radiuses to 100m like so:

```
CLCircularRegion(circularRegionWithCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: queryLat, longitude: queryLong), radius: 100.0, identifier: tuple[location])
```

Entering regions:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
    NSLog("Entering region... " + region.identifier)
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I would enter in both regions instead of just one? Is there any way to improve this radius accuracy? I have tried looking at all sorts of links like http://www.kevfoo.com/2012/07/Core-Location-The-Missing-Details/ and [iOS Geofence CLCircularRegion monitoring. locationManager:didExitRegion does not seem to work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866097/ios-geofence-clcircularregion-monitoring-locationmanagerdidexitregion-does-not) but I can't seem to find a solution to only entering in one region. All help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I know it has been long time to this question, but in Geofencing I am facing problem. I have selected 100 meters radius and 'upon exit' notification should come. But I am getting notification on/around 250 meters. Please help me out.