# Debugging ios geofence intermittent issue

Tags: ios, geofencing

We have an app which is monitoring one location. Lately we have noticed that sometimes, ios app doesn't send notification for `enter`. Things are working fine with android app.

I was reading up on the documentation and the only litmition i found is that an app can only track 20 locations. Which isn't the case in our app. We are tracking only 1 location.

I also looked into if the app has proper implementation and it does, thats why we get notifications sometimes and sometimes we don't.

The other thing that i could think of is if the cell phone was in `Low Power Mode`. That's one pointer for me so far.

Is there anything else that i could look into to figure out the issue?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47099174/5175709) and the other answers to the question. Disclaimer: I'm not sure how valid the answers are or how geofencing has improved itself over the years

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Geofence CLCircularRegion monitoring. locationManager:didExitRegion does not seem to work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866097/ios-geofence-clcircularregion-monitoring-locationmanagerdidexitregion-does-not)